# Does anyone know how to convert NSDate to Date(ticks)?

Tags: .net, objective-c, json, nsdate

Does anyone know how to convert a NSDate to JSON Date(ticks) to have sent to a .net web service?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see "ticks" in the javascript Date documentation, but based on an earlier question of yours you're after milliseconds since 1970.

```
[date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;
```